# Let $E = (0,1) \cup (1,2) \ldots \cup (n,n+1) \cup \ldots$ find the sets of respectively interior, accumulation, isolated and boundary points.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

1. Set of interior points of E: Let $x \in E$, then $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x \in (n,n+1)$. Let $c = \mbox{min} \{|x - n|,|(n+1) - x|\} > 0$ so we have that $(x-c,x+c) \subset (n,n+1) \subset E$. Since $x \in E$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ are arbitrary then the set of interior points of E is E itself.
2. Set of accumulation points of E: 3 cases: (i) let $x \in E$, then $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x \in (n,n+1)$. Since $(n,n+1) \subset E$, for every $c = \mbox{min} \{|x - n|,|(n+1) - x|\} > 0$, $(x-c,x+c) \cap E$ contains infinitely many points of E. (ii) let $x \notin E$ but $x=0$ then for every $0<c<1$ $(x-c,x+c) \cap E$ contains infinitely many points of E. (iii) let $x \notin E$ but $x \in \mathbb{N}$ then for every $0<c<1$ $(x-c,x+c) \cap E$ contains infinitely many points of E. Therefore the set of accumulation points of E is $ \{0\} \cup \mathbb{N} \cup E = \{0\} \cup \mathbb{R}^+$.
3. Set of isolated points:let $x \in E$, then $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x \in (n,n+1)$ then for every $c = \mbox{min} \{|x - n|,|(n+1) - x|\} > 0$, $(x-c,x+c) \subset E$ with $(x-c,x+c)$ containning rational and irrational numbers then $(x-c,x+c) \cap E = (x-c,x+c) \neq \{x\}$. So the set of isolated points of E is the empty set.
4. Set of boundary points: let $x \in \{0\} \cup \mathbb{N}$ (so $x \notin \mathbb{N}$) then every interval $(x-c,x+c)$, $c>0$, contains at least one point in E that is $(x-c,x+c) \cap E \neq \phi$ and $(x-c,x+c)$ contains at least one point that does not belong to E, that is $x$ itself. Then the set of boundary points is $\{0\} \cup \mathbb{N}$.

In the above I would like to know if the given **justifications** (proofs) are correct?

Comment: In $1.)$, I recommend using $(x-\frac{1}{2}c, x+\frac{1}{2}c)$, just to keep away from the end points.  But besides that it seems fine.